# Why can't WordPress access the file system?

Tags: php, wordpress

A client informed me that any time he tries to update a plugin, he gets an error:

> To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.

I don't have FTPd setup on the server, but this seems like a basic permissions issue, right? I've never had to use FTP credentials to update any other WordPress installations.

Well, I did some reading and started messing with permissions and long story short, out of frustration, I eventually made everything writeable by everybody:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 src
```

But I'm still getting the same error. So it has to be some type of configuration issue, right?

I ran a few `find . -exec grep` commands to determine if there is a hard-coded document root (like in Joomla), but I came up empty handed.

- Do I really have to install FTPd to be able to update WordPress from the admin interface?
- Is there a config file somewhere that specifies the document root location?
- Is there some other configuration option that I'm missing here?

Or maybe it's something in the database? The site was originally on a shared host but was moved to a DigitalOcean VPS a month or so ago.

Comment: The root of the folder needs to be writable, but this can open you up to a whole new host of vulnerabilities and security issues. I would highly recommend updating the files for the client. It takes minimal time and effort and allows you retain control of the file permissions. If WordPress has it their way all files would be 777.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to force WordPress to use the filesystem instead of FTP by setting the `FS_METHOD` constant in `wp-config.php`:

```
 define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

More details can be found in the [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants).

Comment: great sir, wordpress is new for me i spend more than a hour for this solution , thanks a lot again  @Ben

Answer (score 0):

Try running `chown -R apache:apache` on the directory. I recall running in to an issue with ownership even when permissions were OK. You may have more success posting this on ServerFault as well.

Comment: I'm using `nginx`. The webserver runs under user/group `www-user:www-data`. This is not the issue.